How to deploy ml model into omnet ++
i trained a  deep learning model with tensorflow and keras for classification problems (ddos attack),
now i want to deploy this model to omnet ++ . I tried with docker but didnt work well for windows , so now what the easiest way to deploy ml model in omnet ++

a related presentation from the OMNeT++ summit: https://summit.omnetpp.org/2022/assets/pdf/pres-nnwifi.pdf and video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ed1_mxNrQYs

i checked it and i tried it , now the problem is in omnet ++ when i run it says no more events simulation terminated  , something like that
